Span figure over two pages without caption
This answer by Martin Scharrer provides a possibility to span a figure over two pages: How do I make a figure that spans a spread of two pages?.
Regarding this answer two question arising:

How can I get rid of the caption? I tried to replace "\caption{#3}%" by "%\caption{#3}%" but without success.
If one looks very closely, the two halves of the pictures are not perfectly aligned vertically. How can this be fixed?
Any help is greatly appreciated!


Have a look at the hvfloat package

The linked solution seemed rather complicated, but starting only on even pages can be tricky.  The solution for [bt] does not work for [p].  There is also a problem passing the figure options (see How to change default float options for figures?).
The b and t options use \afterpage to force the two figures to different pages, so you don't have to mess with \topnumber etc.  Avoid having other floats in the queue.
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.7}% default is 0.3 which is too small

\newcommand{\evenpagepicture}[1]{% #1 = float option
  \begin{figure}[#1]
    \adjustbox{clip=true,trim=0pt 0pt {\textwidth} 0pt}{\usebox\tempbox}
  \end{figure}
  \afterpage{\begin{figure}[#1]
    \adjustbox{clip=true,trim={\textwidth} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\box\tempbox}
  \end{figure}}%
}
\newcommand{\fullpagepicture}[1]{% #1 = float option
  \begin{figure}[#1]\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}% take up the whole page
    \adjustbox{clip=true,trim=0pt 0pt {\textwidth} 0pt}{\usebox\tempbox}
  \end{minipage}\end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[#1]\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \adjustbox{clip=true,trim={\textwidth} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\box\tempbox}
  \end{minipage}\end{figure}%
}
\newenvironment{twopagepicture}[1][b]{% #1 = single float option (t, b or p)
    \xdef\TPP{#1}% save argument
    \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}\begin{minipage}{2\textwidth}\centering
}{%
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
    \global\setbox\tempbox=\copy\tempbox
    \par
    \if p\TPP\relax% full page float
      \ifodd\value{page}
        \expandafter\fullpagepicture\expandafter{\TPP}%
      \else
        \afterpage{\expandafter\fullpagepicture\expandafter{\TPP}}%
      \fi
    \else% bottom  or top float
      \ifodd\value{page}
        \afterpage{\expandafter\evenpagepicture\expandafter{\TPP}}%
      \else
        \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen\relax% rarely happens
          \setlength{\pagegoal}{\textheight}%
          \setlength{\pagetotal}{0pt}%
        \fi
        \ifdim\ht\tempbox>\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\textfloatsep\relax% not enough room on this page
           \afterpage{\afterpage{\expandafter\evenpagepicture\expandafter{\TPP}}}%
        \else
          \expandafter\evenpagepicture\expandafter{\TPP}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
%\lipsum[1-6]% start on page 2

\begin{twopagepicture}[b]
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth, height=0.5\textheight]{example-image}
\end{twopagepicture}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}


This works like a charm! Thanks a lot!
